# Как избавиться от наследования модального окна?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Проблема такая: есть блок с модальным окном и двумя кнопками:
[image: вид блока]

Одна кнопка должна сделать переход по ссылке (но открывается модальное окно).
Вторая - открывает модальное окно.

Что я делаю неправильно и как победить открытие модального окна первой кнопкой?

[image: ошибка с модальным окном]

Comment: Вам вряд ли кто-то поможет пока вы не добавите весь код

Comment: Очевидно, чтобы понять в чем проблема нужен не только Html, но и js и css

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответ !